# Powershell is not able to get session

Tags: powershell-4.0

I'm trying to run one command through powershell but it's giving me below error. My version of powershell is 4.0 and after running

```
Enable-PSRemoting -force
```

it's giving me message as

```
WinRM is already set up to receive requests on this computer.
WinRM is already set up for remote management on this computer.
```

error message is below.

```
[exec] WARNING: Not able to get a session, attempt 10 of 10
[exec] [DIDNARU01INA6.apac.SAS.com] Connecting to remote server DIDNARU01INA6.apac.SAS.com failed with the following error message : The client cannot connect to the destination specified in the request. Verify that the service on the destination is running and is accepting requests. C
[exec] At C:\Tetris\Install\Tools\Modules\Session.psm1:75 char:32
[exec] +             if($attempt -ge $attempts) {throw "$error"}
```

Comment: You try to run this cmd : `Enable-PSRemoting -force ` on your local computer (where you execute script) or on the remote server ?

Comment: Also, did you verify that you can actually connect to the remote server on port tcp/5985 or tcp/5986?

Comment: i'm trying to run on my local computer

Comment: DIDNARU01INA6 is name of my local machine.

Comment: @ Ansgar...u said.. 
Also, did you verify that you can actually connect to the remote server on port tcp/5985 or tcp/5986? –.. How can I check this?

Comment: Have a look at this link : [TUTO PowerShell Commands on Remote Computers](http://www.howtogeek.com/117192/how-to-run-powershell-commands-on-remote-computers/). This describe how to config the remote session. On remote and local computer

Comment: The `Enable-PSRemoting -force` must be run on the REMOTE server, not the local

Comment: when I run Get-Item WSMan:\localhost\Shell\MaxMemoryPerShellMB command it's gives me                                                                       WSManConfig: Microsoft.WSMan.Management\WSMan::localhost\Shell

Type            Name                           SourceOfValue   Value
----            ----                           -------------   -----
System.String   MaxMemoryPerShellMB                            4096                                .Is there any chance that I might have exhausted this max limit ?

Comment: The `telnet` command is one way to check if connections to a remote port are possible: `telnet server.example.org 5985`. Since Microsoft in their infinite wisdom decided to remove the command from the default install you may need to install it first, though.